# Flexible, flat - and adhesive - connectors for PCB pin pads?

Tags: pcb, connector, flexible

Apologies in advance that the question is a bit of "does this exist" - but I really cannot remember whether I've actually seen a prototype for something like this; or I've seen an ad for an actual product - or maybe my mind combined images of unrelated ads.

Anyways: I would like to interface with copper pin pads on a PCB that match a, say, 2x5 2.54 mm pin header (basically circular pads, except for the one marking "pin 1", which is typically a square). Typically, the pads have holes, and then male or female pin headers can be inserted in the holes - and that is how I usually interface with them; however this also requires some force when attaching/reattaching. Say, something like this (from [here](https://www.hhtzine.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=99504)) - just without the holes:

[image]

So, I was wondering if there was something like a flexible flat cable, with matching exposed pads, and an adhesive - so you can basically just "stick" the exposed pads of the flexible flat cable, on the copper pin pads of the rigid PCB? And then you could just "unstick" once you're done - and "stick" again once you need to interface?

I guess that would look something like this (taken from [here](https://www.tech-etch.com/flex/index.html); not sure what this product is supposed to do, though):

[image]

The below image is for something completely different (it's from [here](https://blog.adafruit.com/2018/07/25/smart-bandage-can-monitor-wounds-and-deliver-drugs-as-needed/)), but I've edited it, as it shows how I imagine this flexible adhesive connector would be "sticked" on a PCB:

[image]

The other end of the connector would presumably be just a normal FFC cable, e.g. like this (taken from [here](https://www.fasttech.com/product/5494500-soft-replacement-flexible-flat-cable-connector)) - except with 10 pins, if the "sticky" end is supposed to interface with a 2x5 pin header pads:

[image]

Is there an actual product like this out there, that can be bought (that is, not just a prototype in a lab somewhere)?

---

Btw, I am aware there are adhesive flat cables for loudspeakers, like [Ghost Wire 2.0, Super Flat Adhesive Wire](https://sewelldirect.com/products/ghost-wire-2-0-super-flat-adhesive-wire-16-awg-2-conductor-white):

[image]

... which is a similar concept - however, obviously, these dimensions would not be appropriate for interfacing with a 2x5 2.54mm pads for a pin header.

Comment: "Zebra tape" might work, it's commonly used to attach LCDs. Like most adhesives it's not really suitable for repeated use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images you have linked are through hole variants for soldering. The last one is a connector. The stickers are used just to fix the ribon cable, making the whole thing more robust. The sticker prevents an unintentional tear off, since those contacts are very gentle.

I guess, you won't find nothing similar you want. There are pogo pin connectors if you have ENIG finished board, in case of HASL there is no such variant that will make a good contact, so the manufactures won't produce any.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the "no such variant that will make a good contact, so the manufactures won't produce any" makes a lot of sense - so it's good to have it confirmed, that something like this (adhesive flat connector) probably doesn't exist on the market.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly. You do not state if what you are looking for should be very cheap (i.e. packaged with every product) or for your own testing.

If it is for your own testing you might want to look at Tag-connect cables. With these you can program/interface with round pads while having no connector mounted on your pcb.

Comment: Thanks @Bonnevie - I you're right, I should have stated it's primarily for my own testing (and assuming production, I'd imagine the pads as the part of the PCB layout would have the only thing in the production itself). Thanks for the Tag-connect suggestion, just looked into it - that looks pretty good, although I'd image it also requires a bit of force to connect and disconnect through the Tag-connect holes, which is what I hoped an "adhesive flat connector" would have obviated (if it existed, that is).

Comment: Some of them are a bit more tight than others. You can also get them without plastic legs where you can put a "lock" of sorts on the other side of the PCB (haven't tried it yet). Their edge-connect is also interesting!